# IEEE 754 floating point, what is the largest number < 1?

Tags: c++

When using IEEE 754 floating point representation (`double` type in c++), numbers that are very close to (representable) integers are rounded to their closest integer and represented exactly.  Is that true?
Exactly how close does a number have to be to the nearest representable integer before it is rounded?
Is this distance constant?
For example, given that 1 can be represented exactly, what is the largest `double` less than 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When using IEEE 754 floating point representation (`double` type in
>   c++), numbers that are very close to (representable) integers are
>   rounded to their closest integer and represented exactly.

This depends upon whether the number is closer to the integer than to other values representable. [`0.99999999999999994` is not equal to `1`, but `0.99999999999999995` is.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edb7c6a663169440)

> Is this distance constant?

No, it becomes less with larger magnitudes - in particular with larger exponents in the representation. Larger exponents imply larger intervals to be covered by the mantissa, which in turn implies less precision overall.

> For example, what is the largest double less than 1?

`std::nexttoward(1.0, 0.0)`. E.g. [`0.999999999999999889` on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22a425264611ec95).

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question slightly to make it less misleading I hope.

Answer (score 2):

You will find much more definitive statements regarding the opposite direction from 1.0
The difference between 1.0 and the next larger number is documented here:

[`std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)

The way floating point works, the next smaller number should be exactly half as far away from 1.0 as the next larger number.

Answer (score 2):

The first IEEE double below 1 can be written unambiguously as 0.99999999999999989, but is exactly 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875.

The distance is *not* constant, it depends on the exponent (and thus the magnitude) of the number. Eventually the gap becomes larger than 1, meaning even (not as opposed to odd - odd integers are the first to get rounded) integers will get rounded somewhat (or, eventually, a lot).

Answer (score 0):

The binary representation of increasing IEEE floating point numbers can be seen as a increasing integer representation:

Sample Hack (Intel):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    double one = 1;
    std::uint64_t one_representation = *reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t*>(&one);
    std::uint64_t lesser_representation = one_representation - 1;
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&lesser_representation)
              << " [" << lesser_representation
              << "] < " << *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&one_representation)
              << " [" << one_representation
              << "]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0.9999999999999999 [3fefffffffffffff] < 1 [3ff0000000000000]
```

When advancing the integer representation to its limits, the difference of consecutive floating point numbers is increasing, if exponent bits change.

See also: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Answer (score -2):

> When using IEEE 754 floating point representation (double type in c++), numbers that are very close to exact integers are rounded to the closest integer and represented exactly. Is that true?

This is false.

> Exactly how close does a number have to be to the nearest int before it is rounded?

When you do a binary to string conversion the floating point number gets rounded to the current precision (for `printf` family of functions the default precision is 6) using the current rounding mode.